# Not Able To Access Kafka Services Outside Docker Image

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I have created a kafka docker image on centos. Here, I am running both Zookeeper and Kafka server on the same image.

I see that the services are up and running inside the docker container. I have tested kafka through kafka-console-producer.sh and kafka-console-consumer.sh scripts provided by Kafka. The required ports are exposed too.

```
PORTS
0.0.0.0:2182->2182/tcp, 22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9093->9093/tcp
```

Below are the configurations done in `server.properties` of Kafka:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9093
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2182
```

I have created a topic inside the docker container.

I am able to access the Kafka services through an external machine (in the same network) using telnet command on the host where my docker image is running.

```
telnet 9093
Trying …
Connected to .
Escape character is ‘^]’.

telnet 2182
Trying …
Connected to .
Escape character is ‘^]’.
```

However, writing data to Kafka topic fails with TimeoutExceptions:

```
2017-12-17 21:30:51 DEBUG NetworkClient:195 - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Using older server API v0 to send API_VERSIONS {} with correlation id 1 to node -1 
2017-12-17 21:30:51 DEBUG NetworkClient:189 - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Recorded API versions for node -1: (Produce(0): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], Fetch(1): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], ListOffsets(2): 0 [usable: 0], Metadata(3): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], LeaderAndIsr(4): 0 [usable: 0], StopReplica(5): 0 [usable: 0], UpdateMetadata(6): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], ControlledShutdown(7): 1 [usable: 1], OffsetCommit(8): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], OffsetFetch(9): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], FindCoordinator(10): 0 [usable: 0], JoinGroup(11): 0 [usable: 0], Heartbeat(12): 0 [usable: 0], LeaveGroup(13): 0 [usable: 0], SyncGroup(14): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeGroups(15): 0 [usable: 0], ListGroups(16): 0 [usable: 0], SaslHandshake(17): 0 [usable: 0], ApiVersions(18): 0 [usable: 0], CreateTopics(19): UNSUPPORTED, DeleteTopics(20): UNSUPPORTED, DeleteRecords(21): UNSUPPORTED, InitProducerId(22): UNSUPPORTED, OffsetForLeaderEpoch(23): UNSUPPORTED, AddPartitionsToTxn(24): UNSUPPORTED, AddOffsetsToTxn(25): UNSUPPORTED, EndTxn(26): UNSUPPORTED, WriteTxnMarkers(27): UNSUPPORTED, TxnOffsetCommit(28): UNSUPPORTED, DescribeAcls(29): UNSUPPORTED, CreateAcls(30): UNSUPPORTED, DeleteAcls(31): UNSUPPORTED, DescribeConfigs(32): UNSUPPORTED, AlterConfigs(33): UNSUPPORTED, AlterReplicaLogDirs(34): UNSUPPORTED, DescribeLogDirs(35): UNSUPPORTED, SaslAuthenticate(36): UNSUPPORTED, CreatePartitions(37): UNSUPPORTED)
2017-12-17 21:30:51 DEBUG NetworkClient:189 - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Sending metadata request (type=MetadataRequest, topics=sifs.email.in) to node <IP>:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) 
2017-12-17 21:30:51 DEBUG NetworkClient:195 - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Using older server API v1 to send METADATA {topics=[sifs.email.in]} with correlation id 2 to node -1 
2017-12-17 21:30:52 DEBUG Metadata:270 - Updated cluster metadata version 2 to Cluster(id = null, nodes = [0.0.0.0:9093 (id: 0 rack: null)], partitions = [Partition(topic = sifs.email.in, partition = 0, leader = 0, replicas = [0], isr = [0], offlineReplicas = [])]) 
2017-12-17 21:30:52 DEBUG NetworkClient:183 - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Initiating connection to node 0.0.0.0:9093 (id: 0 rack: null) org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 50 record(s) for sifs.email.in-0: 55017 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 50 record(s) for sifs.email.in-0: 55017 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 50 record(s) for sifs.email.in-0: 55017 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 50 record(s) for sifs.email.in-0: 55017 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 50 record(s) for sifs.email.in-0: 55017 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 50 record(s) for sifs.email.in-0: 55017 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time 
2017-12-17 21:31:47 INFO  KafkaProducer:341 - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms. 
2017-12-17 21:31:47 DEBUG Sender:177 - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Beginning shutdown of Kafka producer I/O thread, sending remaining records.
```

Let me know on how to write data to Kafka topic from external machine.

Answer (score 0):

This steps resolved my problems to connect from outside of docker container:

1. Docker containers deployed (kafka 0.11 with zookeeper):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51071716/2493852

2. Test connection from inside and outside container:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51071629/2493852