# Kafka-docker: can't produce messages

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I set up kafka in a docker container using this project https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker. I can successfully create and list topics on it, but once I try to produce a message with either

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
```

or

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 0.0.0.0:9092 --topic test
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR Error when sending message to topic test with key: null, value:
>   4 bytes with error:
>   (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s)
>   for test-0: 1536 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time

My *docker-compose.yml* lookes like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: docker.for.mac.localhost
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

I tried different options for the *KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME* property, including *docker.for.mac.localhost* which is supposed to be resolved as the actual docker host ip, and *0.0.0.0*, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this docker-compose, it's working for me:

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
    - 2181:2181/tcp
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:0.11.0.1
    environment:
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: test:1:1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: <<HOST_IP>>:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: <<HOST_IP>>
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: '9092'
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: '999'
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    links:
    - zookeeper:zookeeper
    ports:
    - 9092:9092/tcp
```

Answer (score -3):

Don't use local IPs like `127.0.0.1`. Use the true IP instead.